# Best way to interpolate values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, interpolation, linear-interpolation

I have a table with rate at certain date :

```
          Rates

Id  |     Date      |  Rate
----+---------------+-------
 1  |   01/01/2011  |  4.5
 2  |   01/04/2011  |  3.2
 3  |   04/06/2011  |  2.4
 4  |   30/06/2011  |  5
```

I want to get the output rate base on a simple linear interpolation.

So if I enter 17/06/2011:

```
Date        Rate
----------  -----
01/01/2011  4.5
01/04/2011  3.2
04/06/2011  2.4
17/06/2011  
30/06/2011  5.0
```

the linear interpolation is `(5 + 2,4) / 2 = 3,7`

Is there a way to do a simple query (SQL Server 2005), or this kind of stuff need to be done in a programmatic way (C#...) ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Something like this (corrected):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN next.Date IS NULL  THEN prev.Rate
            WHEN prev.Date IS NULL  THEN next.Rate
            WHEN next.Date = prev.Date  THEN prev.Rate
              ELSE ( DATEDIFF(d, prev.Date, @InputDate) * next.Rate 
                   + DATEDIFF(d, @InputDate, next.Date) * prev.Rate
                   ) / DATEDIFF(d, prev.Date, next.Date)
       END AS interpolationRate 
FROM
  ( SELECT TOP 1 
        Date, Rate 
    FROM Rates
    WHERE Date <= @InputDate
    ORDER BY Date DESC
  ) AS prev
  CROSS JOIN
  ( SELECT TOP 1 
        Date, Rate 
    FROM Rates
    WHERE Date >= @InputDate
    ORDER BY Date ASC
  ) AS next
```

Comment: This is of course what he wants. I just implemented a bad picked special case. BTW. You have a parenthesis to much before your last `DATEDIFF` and your first two `CASE WHEN` should return `Rate` not `Date`. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 7):

As @Mark already pointed out, the `CROSS JOIN` has its limitations. As soon as the target value falls outside the range of defined values no records will be returned.

Also the above solution is limited to one result only. For my project I needed an interpolation for a whole list of x values and came up with the following solution. Maybe it is of interested to other readers too?

```
-- generate some grid data values in table #ddd:
CREATE TABLE #ddd (id int,x float,y float, PRIMARY KEY(id,x));
INSERT INTO  #ddd VALUES (1,3,4),(1,4,5),(1,6,3),(1,10,2),
                         (2,1,4),(2,5,6),(2,6,5),(2,8,2);
SELECT * FROM #ddd;                         

-- target x-values in table #vals (results are to go into column yy):
CREATE TABLE #vals (xx float PRIMARY KEY,yy float null, itype int);
INSERT INTO  #vals (xx) VALUES (1),(3),(4.3),(9),(12);

-- do the actual interpolation
WITH valstyp AS (
  SELECT id ii,xx,
         CASE WHEN min(x)<xx THEN CASE WHEN max(x)>xx THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ELSE 0 END flag,
         min(x) xmi,max(x) xma 
  FROM #vals INNER JOIN #ddd ON id=1 GROUP BY xx,id
), ipol AS (
  SELECT v.*,(b.x-xx)/(b.x-a.x) f,a.y ya,b.y yb 
  FROM valstyp v 
  INNER JOIN #ddd a ON a.id=ii AND a.x=(SELECT max(x) FROM #ddd WHERE id=ii 
             AND (flag=0 AND x=xmi OR flag=1 AND x<xx OR flag=2 AND x<xma))
  INNER JOIN #ddd b ON b.id=ii AND b.x=(SELECT min(x) FROM #ddd WHERE id=ii 
             AND (flag=0 AND x>xmi OR flag=1 AND x>xx OR flag=2 AND x=xma))
)
UPDATE v SET yy=ROUND(f*ya+(1-f)*yb,8),itype=flag FROM #vals v INNER JOIN ipol i ON i.xx=v.xx;

-- list the interpolated results table:
SELECT * FROM #vals
```

When running the above script you will get the following data grid points in table `#ddd`

```
id x  y 
-- -- - 
1  3  4 
1  4  5 
1  6  3 
1  10 2 
2  1  4 
2  5  6 
2  6  5 
2  8  2
```

[[ The table contains grid points for two identities (`id=1` and `id=2`). In my example  I referenced only the `1`-group by using `where id=1` in the `valstyp` CTE. This can be changed to suit your requirements. ]]

and the results table `#vals` with the interpolated data in column `yy`:

```
xx  yy   itype 
--- ---- ----- 
1   2    0     
3   4    0     
4.3 4.7  1     
9   2.25 1     
12  1.5  2
```

The last column `itype` indicates the type of interpolation/extrapolation that was used to calculate the value:

```
0:  extrapolation to lower end
1:  interpolation within given data range
2:  extrapolation to higher end
```

This working example can be found [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/447027/interpolation-and-extrapolation-of-data-in-sql?opt.textResults=true#resultSets).

Comment: Upvoted for dedicated user that answer 5 years later, thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

The trick with CROSS JOIN here is it wont return any records if either of the table does not have rows (1 * 0 = 0) and the query may break. Better way to do is use FULL OUTER JOIN with inequality condition (to avoid getting more than one row)

```
( SELECT TOP 1 
        Date, Rate 
    FROM Rates
    WHERE Date <= @InputDate
    ORDER BY Date DESC
  ) AS prev
  FULL OUTER JOIN
  ( SELECT TOP 1 
        Date, Rate 
    FROM Rates
    WHERE Date >= @InputDate
    ORDER BY Date ASC
  ) AS next
ON (prev.Date <> next.Date) [or Rate depending on what is unique]
```