# Interpolate Missing Values in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, interpolation, missing-data

I want to interpolate missing values and update my table accordingly in SQL server 2012

For example my data is as follow:

```
Week_Number  Var1   Output_Var
1            10         10
2            20         20
3           NULL        22.5
4           NULL        25.0
5           NULL        27.5
7            30         30
```

The output of var1 should look like Output_Var variable.

Comment: Checkout:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569376/best-way-to-interpolate-values-in-sql?lq=1

Answer (score 4):

```
declare @alo as table(x int, y float);
insert into @alo (x,y) values (1,10);
insert into @alo (x,y) values (2,20);
insert into @alo (x,y) values (3,null);
insert into @alo (x,y) values (4,null);
insert into @alo (x,y) values (5,null);
insert into @alo (x,y) values (6,30);

SELECT this.x as [X], isnull(this.y,
    (
        SELECT    CASE WHEN next.x IS NULL  THEN prev.y
                       WHEN prev.x IS NULL  THEN next.y
                       WHEN next.x = prev.x THEN prev.y
                       ELSE prev.y + ( (next.y - prev.y) * (this.x - prev.x) / (next.x - prev.x) )
                  END 
        FROM
            ( SELECT TOP 1 X, Y FROM @alo WHERE x <= this.x and y is not null ORDER BY x DESC ) AS prev
            CROSS JOIN
            ( SELECT TOP 1 X, Y FROM @alo WHERE x >= this.x and y is not null ORDER BY x ASC ) AS next
        )) as [Y]
FROM @alo this order by this.x ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can estimate you missing values using the [simple linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) technique, see the "[numerical example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Numerical_example)".

Comment: How is this possible in SQL Server 2012

Comment: I don't think there is a native or built-in method in SQL Server to do it.

Comment: You can see some examples to inspire you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569376/best-way-to-interpolate-values-in-sql

Comment: I am very new to SQl Server.. Can you please built a prototype for me.

Comment: This solution doesn't really seem to contribute anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like that (from [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Numerical_example)):

```
declare @alo as table(x int, y float);
insert into @alo (x,y) values
(1,10),
(2,20),
(3,null),
(4,null),
(5,null),
(6,30)
;
declare @sumtable as table(sx int ,sy int ,sx2 int,sy2 int ,sxy int, n int );

insert into @sumtable
select 
SUM(d.x) as sx,
SUM(d.y) as sy,
SUM(d.x2) as sx2,
SUM(d.y2) as sy2,
SUM(d.xy) as sxy,
count(0) as n
from (

    select
    x, x*x as x2,
    y, y*y as y2,
    x*y as xy
    from @alo
    where x is not null and y is not null
)  D



declare @sx int = (select sx from @sumtable), 
        @sx2 int = (select sx2 from @sumtable),
        @sy int= (select sy from @sumtable), 
        @sy2 int= (select sy2 from @sumtable),
        @sxy int= (select sxy from @sumtable),
        @n int =  (select n from @sumtable);


declare @b as float = cast((@n*@sxy- @sx*@sy) as float)/ cast((@n*@sx2 - @sx*@sx) as float);
declare @a as float = (1.0/@n)*@sy - @b*(1.0/@n)*@sx;


update @alo 
set y = @b*x+@a
where y is null

select * from @alo
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But its seems to be incorrect as Null are replace by 38,50 and 62, but actually it should be replace by 22.5, 25 and 27.5 .

Comment: There were indeed two mistakes, one on the data, and the other on the linear function coefs. I inverted them, must read y = @b*x+@a, I edited the answer

Comment: I also set @alo.y as float to have more accurate values, the result is : (1,10),(2,20),(3,19.99),(4,23.57),(5,27.14),(6,30) you will not have what you expected because this is an estimation method. If you remove the first value on your data (1,10), now you will have what you expected because you will interpolate between two values and not a linear regression estimation