# Performing interpolation on a table, grouping by a 3rd field

Tags: sql, sql-server, linear-interpolation

I have a SQL Server 2008+ table with three columns:

```
Delta (float)
Rate (float)
and Date (datetime)
```

I need to be able to generate a table of rates for all delta for a given date, interpolating if necessary. I can do this fine for single values of Delta, but doing it for all Delta at the same time is stumping me.

Some example data is

```
Rate    ForwardDate             Delta
1.3528  2013-09-30 00:00:00.000 -0.9
1.3528  2013-09-30 00:00:00.000 -0.75
1.3528  2013-09-30 00:00:00.000 -0.5
1.3528  2013-09-30 00:00:00.000 -0.25
1.3528  2013-09-30 00:00:00.000 -0.1
7.121   2013-10-30 00:00:00.000 -0.9
7.152   2013-10-30 00:00:00.000 -0.75
7.387   2013-10-30 00:00:00.000 -0.5
7.972   2013-10-30 00:00:00.000 -0.25
8.564   2013-10-30 00:00:00.000 -0.1
6.972   2013-12-30 00:00:00.000 -0.9
7.035   2013-12-30 00:00:00.000 -0.75
7.405   2013-12-30 00:00:00.000 -0.5
8.275   2013-12-30 00:00:00.000 -0.25
9.187   2013-12-30 00:00:00.000 -0.1
7.185   2014-03-30 00:00:00.000 -0.9
7.321   2014-03-30 00:00:00.000 -0.75
7.82    2014-03-30 00:00:00.000 -0.5
8.919   2014-03-30 00:00:00.000 -0.25
10.075  2014-03-30 00:00:00.000 -0.1
7.755   2014-09-30 00:00:00.000 -0.9
7.92    2014-09-30 00:00:00.000 -0.75
8.485   2014-09-30 00:00:00.000 -0.5
9.76    2014-09-30 00:00:00.000 -0.25
11.175  2014-09-30 00:00:00.000 -0.1
```

The best I have come up with so far is:

```
(
SELECT Delta, ( DATEDIFF(d, @PreviousDate, @ForwardDate) * NextRate 
                   + DATEDIFF(d, @ForwardDate, @NextDate) * PreviousRate
                   ) / DATEDIFF(d, @PreviousDate, @NextDate) AS Rate

FROM 
 (SELECT Main.Delta AS Delta, PR.Rate AS PreviousRate, NR.Rate AS NextRate
  FROM @RatesTable Main
  INNER JOIN @RatesTable PR on PR.Delta = Main.Delta AND PR.ForwardDate = @PreviousDate
  INNER JOIN @RatesTable NR on NR.Delta = Main.Delta AND NR.ForwardDate = @NextDate) AS PrevNextRateTable);
```

Where `@NextDate` and `@PreviousDate` are from an earlier calculation to determine the dates in the table nearest to the test date (`@ForwardDate`). This is needed, as we need to ensure that all interpolations are between the same two dates (giving NULL if one value is missing on one of the dates). I don't want to interpolate between different dates for each value of delta.

This gives me what appears to be a cross join of results

```
Delta   Rate
-0.9    7.742609
-0.75   7.906979
-0.5    8.470543
-0.25   9.741717
-0.1    11.15109
-0.9    7.742609
-0.75   7.906979
-0.5    8.470543
-0.25   9.741717
-0.1    11.15109
-0.9    7.742609
-0.75   7.906979
-0.5    8.470543
-0.25   9.741717
-0.1    11.15109
-0.9    7.742609
-0.75   7.906979
-0.5    8.470543
-0.25   9.741717
-0.1    11.15109
-0.9    7.742609
-0.75   7.906979
-0.5    8.470543
-0.25   9.741717
-0.1    11.15109
```

with 5 results for each delta. I can `SELECT DISTINCT` this if necessary, but can't help but think it's cheating and I'm doing something wrong. Is there any better way that eliminates the need for `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: Similar problem has been solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6569376/3248346

Comment: That's where I improved my original interpolation calculation from. That one only deals with returning 1 value though, I need a table of interpolated values grouped by delta and I'm having problems figuring out how to do it without resorting to the DISTINCT

Comment: Use a group by on the delta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Delta, ( DATEDIFF(d, @PreviousDate, @ForwardDate) * NextRate 
                   + DATEDIFF(d, @ForwardDate, @NextDate) * PreviousRate
                   ) / DATEDIFF(d, @PreviousDate, @NextDate) AS Rate

FROM 
 (SELECT Main.Delta AS Delta, PR.Rate AS PreviousRate, NR.Rate AS NextRate
  FROM @RatesTable Main
  INNER JOIN @RatesTable PR on PR.Delta = Main.Delta AND PR.ForwardDate = @PreviousDate
  INNER JOIN @RatesTable NR on NR.Delta = Main.Delta AND NR.ForwardDate = @NextDate) AS PrevNextRateTable
GROUP BY Delta,
        ( DATEDIFF (d, @PreviousDate, @ForwardDate) * NextRate 
                   + DATEDIFF(d, @ForwardDate, @NextDate) * PreviousRate
                   ) / DATEDIFF(d, @PreviousDate, @NextDate) ;
```