# How to apply a parametrised SQLITE query to each row of a table returned by another query (in the context of interpolation)?

Tags: sql, sqlite, time-series, interpolation

### Input

My input consists of **x_0_y_0** and **x_1**.

**x_0_y_0** (table **dates**) contains the dates and values of the form:

```
timestamp   value
2000-01-01  1
2000-01-03  3
2000-01-05  5
```

**x_1** (query **dates_to_interpolate**) contains the dates of the form:

```
timestamp
2000-01-01
2000-01-02
2000-01-03
2000-01-04
2000-01-05
```

### Output

My desired output **x_1_y1** (query **interpolation_results**) would be of the form:

```
timestamp    value
2000-01-01   1
2000-01-02   2
2000-01-03   3
2000-01-04   4
2000-01-05   5
```

### Method (Attempt)

Using info in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569376/best-way-to-interpolate-values-in-sql) thread and some native sqlite syntax I managed to get a query which gives an interpolated value (say **4**) for a single selected date, say **'2000-01-04'**.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN next.timestamp IS NULL  THEN prev.value
            WHEN prev.timestamp IS NULL  THEN next.value
            WHEN next.timestamp = prev.timestamp  THEN prev.value
              ELSE ( ( julianday(date('2000-01-04')) - julianday(prev.timestamp) ) * next.value
                +    ( julianday(next.timestamp) - julianday(date('2000-01-04')) ) * prev.value
                   ) / (julianday(next.timestamp) - julianday(prev.timestamp))
       END AS interpolated_value 
FROM 
(SELECT dates.timestamp, dates.value FROM dates WHERE dates.timestamp <= date('2000-01-04') ORDER BY dates.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) AS prev
CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT dates.timestamp, dates.value FROM dates WHERE dates.timestamp >= date('2000-01-04') ORDER BY dates.timestamp ASC LIMIT 1) AS next
```

Now I would like to parametrise this using **@interpolation_date** rather than **'2000-01-04'** so I have a function of the form **interpolated_value()**. It seems this could work if I was to call this programatically (say from Python or MATLAB). The problem is that I would like to apply interpolated_value() to **dates_to_interpolate** using sqlite syntax only (in a single query). I found out that sqlite does not support parameters in views, it does not support custom functions. I did see attempts at implementing loops (which I think I might need here); loops seems to involve **recursive triggers** or **WITH** syntax which I am not quite familiar with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
SELECT timestamp,
       (...) AS value
FROM x1;
```

This can simply be done by making the other query a correlated subquery, i.e., just replace `'2000-01-04'` with `x1.timestamp` wherever it occurs:

```
SELECT timestamp,
       (SELECT CASE WHEN next.timestamp IS NULL  THEN prev.value
                    WHEN prev.timestamp IS NULL  THEN next.value
                    WHEN next.timestamp = prev.timestamp  THEN prev.value
                      ELSE ( ( julianday(x1.timestamp) - julianday(prev.timestamp) ) * next.value
                        +    ( julianday(next.timestamp) - julianday(x1.timestamp) ) * prev.value
                           ) / (julianday(next.timestamp) - julianday(prev.timestamp))
               END AS interpolated_value 
        FROM 
        (SELECT dates.timestamp, dates.value FROM dates WHERE dates.timestamp <= x1.timestamp ORDER BY dates.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) AS prev
        CROSS JOIN 
        (SELECT dates.timestamp, dates.value FROM dates WHERE dates.timestamp >= x1.timestamp ORDER BY dates.timestamp ASC LIMIT 1) AS next
       ) AS value
FROM x1;
```

Comment: Works well. It is a shame my method is terribly slow though. For 4000 dates it takes around **4 min and 33 s** to interpolate.

Comment: How to optimize a query would be a separate question, and would require the database schema.